# Contract m-repeated numbers in list to n-repeated (n<m) in place in O(1) space

Tags: python-3.7, array-algorithms

I want to write a `python 3.7` function that has a sorted list of numbers as an input, and a number `n` which is the max number each one of the integers can be repeated and modifies the list in place, so that any numbers that are repeated more than `n` times, would be cut to `n` repeats, and it should be done in `O(1)` space, no additional data structures allowed (e.g. `set()`). Special case - remove duplicates where `n = 1`. Example:

```
dup_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12]
dedup(dup_list, n = 1)
print(dup_list)
[1, 2, 3, 7, 12]

dup_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12]
dedup(dup_list, n = 2)
print(dup_list)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 12]

dup_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12]
dedup(dup_list, n = 3)
print(dup_list)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 12]
```

Case `n = 1` is easy, the code is below (code is taken from `Elements of Prograqmming Interviews, 2008, page 49` except the last line `return dup_list[:write_index]`):

```
def dedup(dup_list):                                                                                                       
    if not dup_list:                                                                                                       
        return 0                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                           
    write_index = 1                                                                                                        
    for i in range(1, len(dup_list)):                                                                                      
        if dup_list[write_index-1] != dup_list[i]:                                                                         
            dup_list[write_index] = dup_list[i]                                                                            
            write_index += 1                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
    return dup_list[:write_index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def dedup2(dup_list, n):
    count = 1
    list_len = len(dup_list)
    i = 1
    while i < list_len:
        if dup_list[i - 1] != dup_list[i]:
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
            if count > n:
                del(dup_list[i])
                i -= 1
                list_len -= 1
        i += 1
    return dup_list

print(dedup2([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9], 1))
```